# Working with ashx and HTML

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

Hi all I am new to ajax programming and asp.net

I have a .ashx file which handles uploading of files on to the server. I am making an ajax call in a html page as below and it does work perfectly in visual studio

```
$.post("FileHandler.ashx", function (data) {
}
```

Now i have copied the .ashx and .html file on to the server (inetpub/wwwroot/MyPage) and then open the html page to check the functionality but this time the file is not uploading and in chrome debugger in network tab I see below information for the FileHandler.ashx

Method: POST
 Status: (canceled)

Is it something i am doing wrong, please help

Comment: ajax upload with `$.post()` can't be used. You need to use `$.ajax()` with `FormData` method.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("filename", $('#file').val()); // append the file in the form data.
$.ajax({
  url: "FileHandler.ashx",
  type: "POST",
  data: fd,
  processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
  contentType: false   // tell jQuery not to set contentType
  success:function(){},
  error:function(){}
});
```

#### [More Docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects)

Comment: The code is working fine with visual studio but when i push the files to the server it wasn't working